# django class-based views with inline model-form or formset

Tags: django, inline-formset, django-class-based-views

I have the following models:

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(_("Date of bill"),null=True,blank=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"),max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField(_("Price"))
    quantity = models.IntegerField(_("Quantity"))
    bill = models.ForeignKey("Bill",verbose_name=_("Bill"),
                             related_name="billitem")
```

I know that this is possible:

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
inlineformset_factory(Bill, Item)
```

and then process this via standard view.

Now I was wondering, if there is a way to achieve the same (meaning: using a inline for adding/editing items belonging to a bill) using **class based views** (not for the admin-interface).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Key points is:

1. generated `FormSet`s within `forms.py` using `inlineformset_factory`:

   ```
   BookImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(BookForm, BookImage, extra=2)
   BookPageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(BookForm, BookPage, extra=5)
   ```
2. returned the `FormSet`s within a `CreateView` class in `views.py`:

   ```
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(BookCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       if self.request.POST:
           context['bookimage_form'] = BookImageFormSet(self.request.POST)
           context['bookpage_form'] = BookPageFormSet(self.request.POST)
       else:
           context['bookimage_form'] = BookImageFormSet()
           context['bookpage_form'] = BookPageFormSet()
       return context
   ```
3. Used `form_valid` to save the form and formset:

   ```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        bookimage_form = context['bookimage_formset']
        bookpage_form = context['bookpage_formset']
        if bookimage_form.is_valid() and bookpage_form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            bookimage_form.instance = self.object
            bookimage_form.save()
            bookpage_form.instance = self.object
            bookpage_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks/')
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
   ```

Comment: I haven't tested the code to see if it actually works, but the source code all looks good.

Comment: I can confirm that the code above works fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to use a class-based *update* view (so UpdateView with inline formsets); the existing model data simply never enters the formset.

Comment: You could *probably* change `BookImageFormSet()` to `BookImageFormSet(instance=self.instance)` although again I haven't tested...

Comment: I think it'd be `self.object`, as opposed to `self.instance`

Comment: @praseodym This code didn't work for me. Did you change the first argument to inlineformset_factory?

Comment: *form_valid* seems like the wrong place for this, as it is usually called after the form has been validated. I think overriding *post* would be the cleaner solution.

Comment: A little late to the party, but this has worked for me and @orokusaki is right about `self.object` instead of `self.instance`.

Comment: While I think the solution is sound, it doesn't make much sense to be checking the request method in `get_context_data()`. Based on the `ProcessFormView` in the Django source, the `get()` and `post()` methods are where you should be instantiating your forms and adding them to the `get_context_data(form=form)` call.

Comment: The example leads to the formsets being recreated when the form is invalid (see `self.get_context_data(form=form)` - this isn't a problem until you have non-form errors in your formset, which appear when you call `formset.is_valid()` (which accesses `formset.errors`, causing an error list to be instantiated). The solution it to reuse the formset (pass it to `get_context_data` and in `get_context_data` check to see if it was provided, only adding it when it's not... or use `post` like the previous comment suggests, which will lead to reusing the formset naturally).

Comment: There seems to be a better treatment of this here: http://kevindias.com/writing/django-class-based-views-multiple-inline-formsets/ but it seems a lot of work to do for just creating which is then replicated for edit, and if you have multiple models with the same setup this starts to become a lot of maintenance (which is what CBV are supposed to help with, aren't they?). Has this been addressed in Django 1.7?

Comment: @CpILL That link you referenced does not work. Rather post code.

Comment: @surfer190 the code I included in the rest of the answer was the code in the remote link.

Comment: @JordanReiter is it possible to pass initial value for a list in model formset ? i have question regarding the same , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56325133/attendance-system-using-django

Answer (score 19):

I just added my own version after checking out some of those pre-made CBVs. I specifically needed control over `multiple formsets -> one parent` in a single view each with individual save functions.

I basically stuffed the FormSet data binding into a `get_named_formsets` function which is called by `get_context_data` and `form_valid`.

There, I check if all formsets are valid, and also look for a method that overrides a plain old `formset.save()` on a per formset basis for custom saving.

The template renders formsets via

```
{% with named_formsets.my_specific_formset as formset %}
 {{ formset }}
 {{ formset.management_form }}
{% endwith %}
```

I think I'll be using this system regularly.

```
class MyView(UpdateView): # FormView, CreateView, etc
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['named_formsets'] = self.get_named_formsets()
        return ctx

    def get_named_formsets(self):
        return {
            'followup': FollowUpFormSet(self.request.POST or None, prefix='followup'),
            'action': ActionFormSet(self.request.POST or None, prefix='action'),
        }

    def form_valid(self, form):
        named_formsets = self.get_named_formsets()
        if not all((x.is_valid() for x in named_formsets.values())):
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

        self.object = form.save()

        # for every formset, attempt to find a specific formset save function
        # otherwise, just save.
        for name, formset in named_formsets.items():
            formset_save_func = getattr(self, 'formset_{0}_valid'.format(name), None)
            if formset_save_func is not None:
                formset_save_func(formset)
            else:
                formset.save()
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect('')

    def formset_followup_valid(self, formset):
        """
        Hook for custom formset saving.. useful if you have multiple formsets
        """
        followups = formset.save(commit=False) # self.save_formset(formset, contact)
        for followup in followups:
            followup.who = self.request.user
            followup.contact = self.object
            followup.save()
```

Comment: This is very clean. I love it :)

Answer (score 12):

You should try out [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views).  Look for `CreateWithInlinesView` and `UpdateWithInlinesView`.

Comment: This appears to fail in Django 2.2

Answer (score 2):

I made some modification to original solution to let formset.is_valid() to work:

```
    if self.request.POST:
        context['fs'] = MyInlineFS(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
    else:
        context['fs'] = MyInlineFS(instance=self.object)
```

Comment: Yes, you are the hero. The delete and update was not working without this.

Answer (score 1):

I red the generic source code of the 1.3-beta-1 :

The code is absolutely not ready for List editing or there is some black magic here.
But I think that it can be implemented quickly.

If you look at the django.view.generic.edit (that support detailed object editing) module how it use the django.view.generic.detail module.

I think that a django.view.generic.list_edit module can be implemented using django.view.generic.list and some part from django.view.generic.edit.

Comment: Yes, I read that part. Though it is not an answer for "automatic" in-lines, as it states there: "A mixin that can be used to display a list of objects." 
I would like to add/edit/delete inlines, not diplay them ;)

Comment: Hixi was wondering if a feature was available with DJANGO -1.3- and using class based view. I red the django source code and the feature is clearly NOT IMPLEMENTED (in django 1.3 beta 1). I give some hint to help to implement not the full developpment.

Answer (score 1):

The code in Jordan's answer didn't work for me. I posted [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198638/django-inline-formset-error/11199031) about this, which I believe I've now solved. The first argument to inlineformset_factory should be Book, *not* BookForm.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to make one more modification to Jordan's and Speq's view's `get_context_data()` in order to have `formset.non_form_errors` exist in the template context.

```
...
if self.request.POST:
    context['fs'] = MyInlineFS(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
    context['fs'].full_clean()  # <-- new
else:
    context['fs'] = MyInlineFS(instance=self.object)
return context
```