# Django inline formset error

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I'm trying to add an inline formset to a form. Here's the minimal code for reproducing the error:

models.py

```
class Festival(Model):
    desc = TextField(max_length=1000)

class FestivalAddress(Model):
    festival = ForeignKey(Festival, related_name="addresses")
    name = CharField(max_length="50")
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^add/$', FestivalCreateView.as_view(), name='festival_add'), 
)
```

views.py

```
class FestivalCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Festival
    form_class = FestivalForm

    #Add FestivalAddressFormset to context here
```

forms.py

```
class FestivalAddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FestivalAddress

class FestivalForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Festival

FestivalAddressFormSet = inlineformset_factory(FestivalForm, FestivalAddress, form=FestivalAddressForm, extra=2)
```

This throws AttributeError: 'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'get_parent_list'. I'm a bit stumped, as I'm following the solution given [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497684/django-class-based-views-with-inline-model-form-or-formset).

**Edit**: I removed FestivalCreateView's usage of the formset because the error occurs with or without it.

Comment: This isn't enough information to solve the problem. FestivalCreateView doesn't even use your formset? You need to update your examples to show how the formset is utilised, and post a full stacktrace.

Comment: Greg - FestivalCreateView was using the formset. I realized that the issue was unrelated to that usage, so I removed that code to make the code clearer.

Comment: Ok, then you should remove all references to the Formset since it's no longer being used in your code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like my call to inlineformset_factory was incorrect. According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/), the first argument should be a model, not a form.

Answer (score 0):

Should have been:

`FestivalAddressFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Festival, FestivalAddress, form=FestivalAddressForm, extra=2)`

Comment: a good example of getting something similar to work http://haineault.com/blog/155/