# Django Formset in generic FormView

Tags: python, django, formset

Hi i used formsets in generic FormView like this:

```
class RequestRecommendationView(FormView):
    template_name = "account/stepfour.html"
    form_class = formset_factory(StepFourForm)

    def form_valid(self,form):
        print form.is_valid()
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        # return redirect(reverse("some_url_name"))
```

form for formset_factory is like this:

```
class StepFourForm(forms.Form):
    contact_person = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    company = forms.CharField(required=True)
    request_message = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

my html structure is like this:

```
<div style="padding-top:100px;padding-left:10px;">
    <h4> Request a Recommendation </h4>
    <form method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <table id="myForm">
                <tbody>
                {% for f in form %}
                    {% for field in f %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{field.label_tag}}</td>
                            <td>{{field}}</td>

                            {% for error in field.errors %}
                            <td><span>{{ error }}</span></td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xlarge" type="submit" name="submit">Request Now</button>
            {{ form.management_form }}
        </form>
</div>
```

Then i used django-dynamic-formset (https://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/)
to add/remove extra forms through these:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
               $('#myForm tbody').formset();
           })
</script>
```

the problem is:
if i leave the form empty,(every field is required), it manages to get to form_valid() of my class-view (though it should not),  if i fill one of the fields (leaving others unfilled), it displays the errors associated message successfully. why is this happening ? what should i do to fix it ? is providing form_class a formset is behind all of this ?

Comment: Don't think forms sets are supported in class based views yet https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16256. However, this might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497684/django-class-based-views-with-inline-model-form-or-formset

Comment: Possibly because an empty formset IS valid, eg. no foreign keys pointing at this model?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views

Comment: @SColvin yep .. empty formset are valid and leaving other fields empty is not valid. Thanks for help

Comment: I know it's been over a year, but if anyone finds this post, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406537/django-formsets-make-first-required

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked 6 years ago, I found it because i faced the same issue, since it is unanswered, I'll provide the solution i found.
according to the documentation to validate a minimum of forms, you have to provide a `min_num` and set `validate_min=True` in the formset_factory:

`formset = formset_factory(your_form, min_num=2, validate_min=True, extra=2)`