# How do I create a simple formset that works?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-3.0

So the code I have:

models.py

```
class Department(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    code_meaning = models.CharField(max_length=250, )

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.code)
```

urls.py

```
path('departments/', DepartmentCreateView.as_view(), name='department'),
```

department.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="content-section">
       
{{ formset.management_form }}
<form method= "POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for form in formset %}
 {{ form}}<br><br>
{% endfor %}
<button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock content%}
```

views.py

```
class DepartmentCreateView(CreateView):
    model =  Department
    form_class = DepartmentForm
    template_name = 'department.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = {'formset': DepartmentFormset}
        return context

   

    def form_valid(self, formset):
        formset.save()

        messages.success(self.request,'Changes were saved.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        

    def get_success_url(self):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

forms.py

```
class DepartmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Department
      fields = ('code', 'code_meaning',)
DepartmentFormset= modelformset_factory(Department, fields=('__all__'))
```

My page shows the formset, but when I click on the submit button it just reloads, don't saves anything and the succes message is also not showed on my home page.
(My other createviews where I have only one form works prefect)

I very new to django so I don't know where I did something wrong ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django class-based views with inline model-form or formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497684/django-class-based-views-with-inline-model-form-or-formset)

Answer (score 0):

VdGR you are trying to use `DepartmentFormset` in your views but there is no `DepartmentFormset` in your forms.py. You should make `DepartmentFormset` in your forms.py then call it in your views. I correct your code and remove `DepartmentFormset` as you don't have any `DepartmentFormset`.

```
class DepartmentCreateView(CreateView):
    model =  Department
    form_class = DepartmentForm
    template_name = 'department.html
  
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context[''messages] = messages.success(self.request,'Changes were saved.')
    return context


    def get_success_url(self):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

you are doing mistake in your context. Context should be call like this:

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context['formset'] =  DepartmentFormset(self.request.POST or None)
    return context
```

then use `formset` in your template for calling  `DepartmentFormset` froms.

Comment: VdGR  I am happy hear  that help you. please don't forget to accept the answare.

Comment: I'm testing your answer atm but why should I do context['formset'], bcs context = {'formset': DepartmentFormset} works to ? Is better to do it the way you say it ?

Comment: VdGR see the doc of django they are using above context  for pass data to html template  in class based view. if  context = {'formset': DepartmentFormset} works then you can use.

Comment: boyenec, the problem you suggest is not that there is not a formset, because otherwise I wouldn't see the formset when I open the page (I think), the problem is that when pressing the submit button the page just reloads and doesn't save the changes

Comment: Did you using `formset.save()`???if yes then use `form.save()`

Comment: I need to be see your views which you are trying now. You are doing mistake  somewhere in your views that's the reason data not saving

Comment: yes `formset.save()` and also tried `if formset.is_valid():
         formset.save()`

Comment: That's the problem.  Use form.save.() and if form.is_valid()

Comment: Also remove fromset inside your function parameters. Just use `def form_valid(self):`

Comment: `def form_valid(self):
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()` 
like so ?
but than is the form not defined ?

Comment: Just use this and try and let me know the result.

Comment: yeah also not working, but is my get_context_data() correct ?

Comment: Copy my whole views.py code and past it in your views. My code should be work. There is no error in code. You are doing mistake in your views that the reason forms not rendering in your html template

Comment: Also remove the for loop in your html template

Comment: yeah the problem is not that the forms are not rendering, they just don't do anything when you click the submit button

Comment: Did you remove for loop in your template?